# AutoFilter via IF and multiple critera

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

Revised question:  The below code adds filters to arrResults.  When the macro goes to filter Field 13 by arrResults(), it only filters by the last value captured.  When running debug and viewing the Immediate window, I do see multiple values captured within the arrResults(), yet the code only filters by the last entry (i.e. if I click "Received/Sent/Fail", only "Fail" would return.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Add_Sheet_Update()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Rng As Range, str1 As String, str2 As String
Dim i As Long, wsName As String, temp As String
Dim arrResults()

With Sheets("All Call Center Detail")
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = .Range("A1:BT" & LastRow)
End With

With Sheets("Search Form")
    str1 = .Range("E9").Text
    str2 = .Range("E13").Text
End With

Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
With Range("R1:S99") ' 2 columns, any # of rows
    For x = 1 To .Rows.Count
        If .Cells(x, 1) Then
            y = y + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrResults(1 To y)
            arrResults(y) = .Cells(x, 2)
            End If
    Next x
End With
Debug.Print Join(arrResults, "/")

Sheets.Add After:=Sheets("Search Form")
ActiveSheet.Name = ("Results")

Sheets("All Call Center Detail").Select
If Not str1 = "" Then Rng.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=str1
If Not str2 = "" Then Rng.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=str2
If y > 0 Then Rng.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=arrResults

Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Results").Range    ("A1")

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

Sheets("Results").Activate
ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit
wsName = Format(Date, "mmddyy")
If WorksheetExists(wsName) Then
    temp = Left(wsName, 6)
    i = 1
    wsName = temp & "_" & i
    Do While WorksheetExists(wsName)
        i = i + 1
        wsName = temp & "_" & i
    Loop
End If

ActiveSheet.Name = wsName
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Bill. Do you have a screenshot or two to support the above description? Here is a great site [to help you improve upon your post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Possibly there are some pointers to help you. Maybe you can also shorten the above post (or is all of it relevant / necessary). Please don't misunderstand. But you are right in your post and it is a bit hard to follow along (at least for me). But maybe you don't have to change anything and someone else here can follow and help you with your problem.

Comment: Hi Ralph - Thank you for the reply.  I've edited my original post in hopes of making the question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `Operator` argument to your `AutoFilter` statement:

```
If y > 0 Then Rng.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=arrResults, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```